# MVC3 URL alternatives

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing

After reviewing A LOT of questions and Internet data, I've solved a problem of mine with getting URL parameter from MVC3 application correctly.
Thing is that there wasn't a fault in coding, but in routing (I'm not so good with routing...). 
Here's the current issue.

```
http://localhost:51561/Report/Details/1
```

This is the way my application presents Report details, which is good. But when it does it like this, I can't get value from URL parameter, like this

```
Request.QueryString["id"]
```

But, when I manually type in URL `http://localhost:51561/Report/Details?id=1` it works...
Thing is i like the first URL type, but I don't know how to get parameter from it...

Help, please...

Update:

My Controller actions:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Report report = db.Reports.Find(id);
        ViewBag.TestID = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        return View(report);
    }

    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        Report report = db.Reports.Find(id);
        var imageData = report.Image;
        return (File(imageData, "image/jpg"));
    }
```

My View:

```
<div class="display-label">Picture</div>
<div class="display-field">
   <img alt="image" src="<%=Url.Action("Show", "Report", new { id = ViewBag.TestID })%>" width="200px" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think your action method is OK, just remove the querystring part. You already have your `id` passed as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `Request.QueryString` in your application. Apart from that, in the first URL, you don't have a query string, and thus you can't access it (also read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on msdn about `Request.QueryString`).

I also would like to suggest you to go through the basic tutorial of ASP.NET MVC3, to be found [**here**](http://www.asp.net/mvc). Many things like your question are thoroughly explained there.

To answer your question now, in your first URL example, the `1` in the URL is a parameter of your action (the Details action). You have to add this parameter to your method (action):

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

UPDATE:
You have apparently the right action (method) declaration. Now, you can just use the parameter `id`. So change the `Request.QueryString["id"]` just by the variable (parameter) `id`.

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    Report report = db.Reports.Find(id);
    ViewBag.TestID = id;
    return View(report);
}
```

There is no need to apply `ToString()` on the id, you shouldn't make it when it isn't necessary (you might need it somewhere else, later or so). Just put it in the `ViewBag` as the original type.

Your `Show()` method is good :). You have now the `id` parameter as you needed. (Try to avoid too many parentheses, it makes it look messy and now so clear.)

```
public ActionResult Show(int id)
{
    Report report = db.Reports.Find(id);
    var imageData = report.Image;
    return File(imageData, "image/jpg");
}
```

Comment: I have done so, and I have been through several basic tutorials. Can you please check the updated question. I would like to avoid going through tutorials over and over, so any alternative for getting that ID to my Show action would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh. Silly me... Thanks a lot... This is my 13th hour of coding a lot of different stuff, I'm overheated...

Comment: Actually it compiles and works fine after altering Details Method. I will look into Show method more now. Thanks once more.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it is good to take a short break, to clear your head and process everything that went on. Then you can start with a clear head ;).

Comment: Okay, the Show indeed should work, there is a `File()` method in the controller class (I don't know all methods by heart :P). You should just use the `File()` method as you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use `Request.QueryString["id"]` in MVC

Just add `id` parameter to your `ReportController.Details` action:

`public ActionResult Details (int id)`

The above is assuming you have a default route setup in Global.asax:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Comment: You can say it is not recommended, but you can still use querystring in your url

Comment: Yes, you can also do `Response.Write`, but you're not supposed to do that, too...